# All homomorphic images of a solvable Lie algebra are solvable?

Tags: lie-algebras

Here I read in a book that:

> All homomorphic images of a solvable Lie algebra are solvable as well.

How to prove such a statement? Let's say we have a homomorphism 
$$\phi: \mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{H},$$ where $\mathcal{G}$ is a solvable Lie algebra and $\phi(0)=\mathcal{I}\in \mathcal{G}$ is the non-trivial kernel of the homomorphism. Then there is $g^{\{i\}}=[g^{\{i-1\}},g^{\{i-1\}}]=0$ for a number $i$. $[\phi(0)\equiv\mathcal{I},\phi(0)\equiv\mathcal{I}]=0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde why $[\mathcal{I},\mathcal{I}]$ must be 0?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, My notation indicates that $\mathcal{I}$ is an ideal rather than a specific element.

Comment: But $\phi(0)$ is a specific element, and not an ideal. So $\phi(0)=I$ imeans that $I=0$. Perhaps you mean $\ker(\phi)=I$ ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, Sorry, I see my problem. I mis-consider $\mathcal{I}$ as an ideal of $\mathcal{H}$. Thanks.

Comment: $\ker(\phi)$ is an ideal in $\mathcal{G}$, not in $\mathcal{H}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $L$ be a solvable Lie algebra. Then all homomorphic images $\phi(L)$ are again solvable, because for the derives series we see inductively that 
$$
\phi(L^ {(n)})=(\phi(L)^ {(n)}.
$$
So if we have $L^{(n)}=0$, because $L$ is solvable, then this implies that also $\phi(L)$ is solvable.

Comment: Homomorphism have to be surjective homomorphism.

Comment: @Spectrum No, $\phi$ need not be surjective. We always have $\phi([L,L])=[\phi(L),\phi(L)]$. If you say that $f\colon L\rightarrow  L_1$ is a *surjective* homomorphism, then even $\phi(L^ {(n)})=L_1^{(n)}$.